# Calling a java Script function from GridView with <% Eval("")%> as a function parameter?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to call a javascript function with a single parameter from a link click inside the GridView Control I need to provide the value of the parameter with `<%Eval("myfield")%>` how can i do this?

```
<ItemTemplate>                                 
     <a href="#" onclick='"javascript:return changeview(<%Eval("Id")%>)"'>
          <asp:Label style="color:white;"  ID="Label1" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("color").ToString())%>' runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("doctorname") %>'>
          </asp:Label>
     </a>                                   
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return changeview(\"{0}\")", Eval("Id").ToString()) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

> ```
> <a href="lnkTest" id="lnkViewContent"  onclick="ShowContent('<%# Eval("Id") %>')">View Content</a>
> ```